# Eclipse Juno jar android dependencies issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on an android project at Eclipse Juno, and so far it has no errors, but I can't export it. I looked at the `Android Console` and I found this:

```
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp] Found 2 versions of android.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp] Versions found are:
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp] Path: D:\installers\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp]  Length: 21841425
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp]  SHA-1: 9d58c29f33a93f486da30401118a4e45a7f208cb
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp] Path: D:\installers\SDK\adt bundle 23\sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp]  Length: 21314433
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp]  SHA-1: 066aafa1a95681f4ff7280f162157ffeb2093e84
[2015-09-26 23:30:22 - HandGestureApp] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I've checked `Java Build Path` at the `Project Properties`, and there is only 1 jar file in it.

How can I fix the Jar mismatch?

Comment: are you using any other library as well? additional libraries may use another version of android support library which may cause problem.

Comment: I've checked the `/lib` as per instructions of @mohax and that did the trick. I've deleted the other jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check also jar files in `/libs` folder in library projects, that you connect to yours main project.